# Overload for different types and their baseclass

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, overloading

Let's assume I have an abstract baseclass `Shape_t` with derived types `Rectangle_t` and `Circle_t`.
There is a generic function `get_area` for both derived types and I would like to overload it as well for the class so that I get the following interfaces (Julianesque notation):

```
get_area(type(Circle_t) :: C)
get_area(type(Rectangle_t) :: R)
! The following leads to ambiguous interfaces
get_area(class(Shape_t) :: S)
```

Unfortunately I get an "ambiguous interface" error, when I try this.
From this I have three questions:

1. Is there anything conceptionally wrong with what I want to achieve? Since variables are explicitly declared as polymorphic (`class(...)`) the compiler can always choose the most specific interface and fall back to the polymorphic interface. So I don't see the ambiguity.
2. If the answer to question 1 is: "There is no conceptional ambiguity". Are there plans in the standard to change this?
3. Is the following code, where a `dyn_get_area` for dynamic polymorphism is introduced, a solid workaround? Note that I would like to stick to static polymorphism as long as possible, i.e. as long as the concrete Shape is known at compile time.

```
module shapes_mod
    implicit none
    private
    public :: Shape_t, Rectangle_t, Circle_t, PI, get_area, dyn_get_area

    real, parameter :: PI = atan(1.0) * 4.0

    type, abstract :: Shape_t
    end type

    type, extends(Shape_t) :: Circle_t
        real :: r = 0.0
    end type

    type, extends(Shape_t) :: Rectangle_t
        real :: a = 0.0, b = 0.0
    end type

    interface get_area
        module procedure get_area_Rectangle_t, get_area_Circle_t
    end interface

    contains

    pure function get_area_Circle_t(C) result(res)
        type(Circle_t), intent(in) :: C
        real :: res
        res = C%r**2 * PI
    end function

    pure function get_area_Rectangle_t(R) result(res)
        type(Rectangle_t), intent(in) :: R
        real :: res
        res = R%a * R%b
    end function

    pure function dyn_get_area(S) result(res)
        class(Shape_t), intent(in) :: S
        real :: res
        select type(S)
        type is(Rectangle_t)
            res = get_area(S)
        type is(Circle_t)
            res = get_area(S)
        end select
    end function

end module


program test_polymorphic_and_static_overload
    use shapes_mod, only: Shape_t, Rectangle_t, Circle_t, get_area, dyn_get_area
    implicit none
    class(Shape_t), allocatable :: random_shape
    type(Circle_t) :: circle
    type(Rectangle_t) :: rectangle
    real :: p

    circle = Circle_t(1.0)
    rectangle = Rectangle_t(1.0, 2.0)

    call random_number(p)
    if (p < 0.5) then
        random_shape = circle
    else
        random_shape = rectangle
    end if

    write(*, *) get_area(circle)
    write(*, *) get_area(rectangle)
    write(*, *) dyn_get_area(random_shape)
end program
```

Comment: What are these #: macros or directives?

Comment: @VladimirF, see https://fypp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fypp.html#preprocessor-language, for example.

Comment: Sorry, if I am back at my computer I replace it with pure Fortran code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortran's rules for selection of a specific procedure from a generic interface, and for how specific procedures in a generic interface must be distinguishable, are designed to be simple to learn and apply.  To avoid the need for any rules describing how a "best match"/"most specific" is selected, in circumstances that might otherwise be ambiguous, the language rules are such that there can be at most one non-elemental procedure and at most one elemental procedure that matches, in any scoping unit  (elemental specifics are only considered if a non-elemental specific does not match).

Your proposed procedures violate these language rules.

I have not seen any realistic proposals to change the rules in a way that would lose the "simple to learn and apply" design intent.

Put a deferred binding in each type that nominates a function that implements the relevant calculation for get_area.  Forward to that binding from the get_shape function (or change references to get_shape to be references to the binding).  Avoid implementing type specific behaviour using SELECT TYPE - type specific behaviour should be implemented using bindings.

Comment: Is it good to add that the explanatory notes explicitly state that the goal of the ambiguity rules is to ensure that selection of a specific procedure can be done before execution commences? That's partly the motivation of prohibition of "most specific"? (And also suggests that design changes are most unlikely.)

Comment: Might depend on definitions, but I'd consider "overloading", for compiled languages, to always be done on the declared type of the arguments (compile time concept) and always be achievable at compile time.  Other compiled languages achieve compile time resolution of overloads in in the face of apparent ambiguity (single argument cases aren't so much the issue - multiple arguments are what make things interesting) - so Fortran obviously could too, but with the downside of the language complexity cost for the necessary disambiguation rules.

Comment: "Most specific on declared type", I agree that note doesn't help. Simple rules, does.  (Happy to delete comments if you are.)

Comment: I realized, that the deferred binding approach has one significant drawback to my example. AFAIK you would have run time overhead for method resolution, even if the type is known at compile time. If you can achieve static polymorphism where possible and only resort to dynamic polymorphism if you have to, I would be happy to hear how you do this.

Comment: Implementation details vary, but typically SELECT TYPE is slower than the overhead of construction of a descriptor for the polymorphic object and the subsequent dynamic dispatch, and if the object is not polymorphic and you directly reference the binding, then there isn't dynamic dispatch.  Pull the class(shape_t) specific out of the generic (just give it a different procedure name) if you really want to overload the get_area identifier for each type.

Comment: > Pull the class(shape_t) specific out of the generic (just give it a different procedure name) if you really want to overload the get_area identifier for each type. 

Isn't this exactly what I did?

>and if the object is not polymorphic and you directly reference the binding, then there isn't dynamic dispatch.
That's good to know. Thank you.